# PHP and Various Single Quotes

Tags: php, wordpress, quotes

using WordPress and adding the title of a post to be

```
Jane's Addiction
```

When it's viewed in the page it comes out as

```
Jane’s Addiction
```

**Please note the different single quote.**

Any sort of replace on the 2nd version of the single quote doesn't seem to work. I want to replace it with a "**normal**" single quote as shown in first example as it doesn't work when using tags.

Thanks,

JJ

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work"

Comment: WP probably runs a filter before displaying the posts

Comment: "Normal" single quotes are typographically incorrect, why would you want to get back to that?

Comment: On the "typographically incorrect" comment, I'd like to add that this is not true in all languages. In Sweden we don't use the fancy quotes and removal of the wptexturize filter is the first thing I add for new themes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apparently caused by the [`wptexturize`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize) function.

While I haven't tried any of these fixes/workarounds myself, [this page](http://www.noobcube.com/quick-tips/wordpress-quick-tips/wordpress-stop-changing-my-quotes-/) does provide a few that you could try.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin created by Alex King called Alex King's wp-unformatted plugin which does the remove filter functions for you so you do not need to make edits to your templates and will work even if you change templates.  The site to download it can be found below:
http://crowdfavorite.com/wordpress/plugins/wp-unformatted/

To use it all you have to do is add a custom field in your post called sandpaper and set the value to 1.  This way you can change it on a per post basis.